# Decryption function not called in php

Tags: java, php, encryption

I am using encryption in java and performing decryption in php.
i am using following code for doing encryption in java.

```
String iv = "fedcba9876543210";
IvParameterSpec ivspec;
KeyGenerator keygen;
Key key;

ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keygen.init(128);
key = keygen.generateKey();

keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES"); 

Cipher cipher;
byte[] encrypted;

cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());

private String padString(String source) {
  char paddingChar = ' ';
  int size = 16;
  int padLength = size - source.length() % size;

  for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++) {
    source += paddingChar;
  }

  return source;
}
```

and for decryption in php i am using this following code:

```
function decrypt($code, $key) {
  $key = $this->hex2bin($key);
  $code = $this->hex2bin($code);

  $td = mcrypt_module_open("rijndael-128", "", "cbc", "fedcba9876543210");

  mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, CIPHER_IV);
  $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);

  mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
  mcrypt_module_close($td);

  return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
}

function hex2bin($hexdata) {
  $bindata = "";

  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
    $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
  }

  return $bindata;
}
```

Encryption is working fine but flow is getting stopped during decryption at this function of php:

```
$td = mcrypt_module_open("rijndael-128", "", "cbc", "fedcba9876543210");
```

so what am i missing?

Comment: What does "getting stopped" mean? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the error you are getting?

Do you have the mcrypt for PHP installed/compiled?  [Info here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.requirements.php)

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying.
i am not getting any error.
Can i get libmcrypt-x.x.tar.gz for mac os john

Comment: when i echo before mcrypt_module_open() function it will print that.
But if i echo after mcrypt_module_open(), it will not print anything.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `die('test');` after it?  If that doesn't work.  You're throwing a fatal error (function not found) and you're not reporting it `error_reporting(0)`?  Check your error log.  You may not have mcrypt installed.

Comment: yes you are right. I have not installed mcrypt.
But now i am facing new problem. I have posted question for the same.
Can u please check the following url.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360762/file-not-found-exception-in-android